# Anything with an MPEG codec plays too fast on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio, video, pulse-audio, mpeg

I'm not sure when, why and how it changed, but at a certain moment video and mp3 files started to run faster than usual (witch chipmunk like speech).

I have a Radeon RX550 card which I use for HDMI output. The OS is Xubuntu 20.04 running Kodi 18. The problem is however not limited to Kodi, other media players show the same problem.

I've been looking for a solution for days.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Only a workaround so you don't go crazy in the meantime. (sorry!) .. SMPlayer .. use the `[` and `]` keys to slow and speed the playback speed. :(  Sorry sir.. I wish I could help more.  I can't imagine why this is happening but there are sure some smart people here. :)  Hopefully, someone will know why.

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/981420

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was hardware related after all. At one point a great force was applied to the HDMI connector which must have damaged a pin related to timing or something. I bought an 8 euro DisplayPort to HDMI adapter and the problem was gone.

Cheers,

BC